# Objects getting deled from Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am using django 1.9 with python 2.7 connected with postgres as backend. When I perform operations on a row stored in postgres, when an exception occurs, the row under operation gets deleted from the backend. I also tried having sqlite3 as the backend and had the same issue.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly have [`ATOMIC_REQUESTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-ATOMIC_REQUESTS) set to `True`, and when an exception is raised the transaction is rolled back.

From the [*Database Transactions* section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests) of the documentation:

> A common way to handle transactions on the web is to wrap each request in a transaction. Set `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` to `True` in the configuration of each database for which you want to enable this behavior.
>
> It works like this. Before calling a view function, Django starts a transaction. If the response is produced without problems, Django commits the transaction. **If the view produces an exception, Django rolls back the transaction.**

Bold emphasis mine.

Set the `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` option to `False` if you don't want this to happen.

Comment: Thank you for responding! This error happens while I am performing operations on a row that has already been saved. If there is an exception, shouldn't only the local changes be rolled back?